# Migrate installation from one HDD to another?

Tags: macos, migration, ubuntu-server

I have a server with a 64 GB SSD inside. It runs just fine, but occasionally there's a hiccup that causes it to nearly fill up. When that happens my server starts to lockup and generally misbehave. I'm looking to buy a bigger SSD (either 128 GB or 256 GB) but I'm a bit unsure of how best to make the transition.

For a start, I don't have an external monitor. If I need one I'll have to borrow it from work. Most of the time I just SSH into the server from my iMac.

The only solution I can think of would be to buy two FW800 2.5" cases, boot from the 64 GB SSD and clone it to the 128 GB SSD. Seem a bit excessive but it might be my best option.

I do have more than one SATA port on my server, but they're all currently being use for storage drives. They don't mount by default, so I could unplug them and just have the two SSDs and do the whole thing via SSH. This is another option I'm considering.

My main concern with either is how best to make sure everything goes across. I want a carbon copy of the first one onto the second. This is especially important because I have a ZFS volume (my storage) and I'm a bit unfamiliar with how to move everything across.

I could just start fresh and reinstall everything on the SSD, but that seems like extra trouble I don't need.

So any advice on how best to achieve my goals would be appreciated. Thanks!

Server is running Ubuntu Server 12.04. The iMac has 10.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Server in question is an Ubuntu-Server there is no need for special forks to be restored. Therefore you could use `rsync` from the iMac to clone the complete 64GB SSD from the server onto a drive attached to your iMac.

You would then have to attach that volume to the ubuntu-server to start from. Or you swap the hard-drive in the server to a bigger one and do the `rsync` the other way round from your Mac to the server.

But what causes the hickups in the first place? Wouldn't it be easier to eliminate the cause for them? As most likely they will occur sooner or later on the larger harddrive as well.

Comment: The problem has to do with any time my server crashes and is restarted SABnzbd+ starts and immediately resumes downloading. However, my ZFS volumes (where it's set to download) weren't mounting automatically (I've done something about this) and it was defaulting to my local boot disk. I may have already sorted the problem, but it would be nice to have a bit more buffer locally.